# AES Implementation in C++

Tags: c++, performance, cryptography, aes

I've implemented AES (128, 192 and 256) in C++ and I'm looking to improve the code to make it not "DIY-crypto-bad", if at all possible. I've also been trying to optimize my code, and so far I've gotten it to the point where I can encrypt a 10MB webm file in about 3s.

Here's the output of my small "Benchmarking" program:

```
Read file, filesize 10878713B, 10.3747MB
Done padding
Encryption of 10878713B (10.3747MB) took 3759.78ms
Average speed of 2.7594MB/s
Decryption of 10878713B (10.3747MB) took 3305.84ms
Average speed of 3.13831MB/s
```

The file is being encrypted in CBC mode. For my Galois multiplications, I've used lookup-tables as calculating them took a very long time. I'm padding the file by inserting the amount of needed padding bytes after the data (PKCS7, if I'm not mistaken).

AES.hpp:

```cpp
/**
 *  @author thomas
 *  @date   01/11/17.
 */

#ifndef AES_HPP
#define AES_HPP

#include <cstring>

//#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <BlockCipher/BlockCipher.hpp>
#include <Util/Types.hpp>
#include <Util/Util.hpp>

namespace Crypto
{
    class AES : public BlockCipher
    {
        private:
            constexpr static uint8 S_BOX [256] =
            {
                    0x63, 0x7C, 0x77, 0x7B, 0xF2, 0x6B, 0x6F, 0xC5, 0x30, 0x01, 0x67, 0x2B, 0xFE, 0xD7, 0xAB, 0x76,
                    0xCA, 0x82, 0xC9, 0x7D, 0xFA, 0x59, 0x47, 0xF0, 0xAD, 0xD4, 0xA2, 0xAF, 0x9C, 0xA4, 0x72, 0xC0,
                    0xB7, 0xFD, 0x93, 0x26, 0x36, 0x3F, 0xF7, 0xCC, 0x34, 0xA5, 0xE5, 0xF1, 0x71, 0xD8, 0x31, 0x15,
                    0x04, 0xC7, 0x23, 0xC3, 0x18, 0x96, 0x05, 0x9A, 0x07, 0x12, 0x80, 0xE2, 0xEB, 0x27, 0xB2, 0x75,
                    0x09, 0x83, 0x2C, 0x1A, 0x1B, 0x6E, 0x5A, 0xA0, 0x52, 0x3B, 0xD6, 0xB3, 0x29, 0xE3, 0x2F, 0x84,
                    0x53, 0xD1, 0x00, 0xED, 0x20, 0xFC, 0xB1, 0x5B, 0x6A, 0xCB, 0xBE, 0x39, 0x4A, 0x4C, 0x58, 0xCF,
                    0xD0, 0xEF, 0xAA, 0xFB, 0x43, 0x4D, 0x33, 0x85, 0x45, 0xF9, 0x02, 0x7F, 0x50, 0x3C, 0x9F, 0xA8,
                    0x51, 0xA3, 0x40, 0x8F, 0x92, 0x9D, 0x38, 0xF5, 0xBC, 0xB6, 0xDA, 0x21, 0x10, 0xFF, 0xF3, 0xD2,
                    0xCD, 0x0C, 0x13, 0xEC, 0x5F, 0x97, 0x44, 0x17, 0xC4, 0xA7, 0x7E, 0x3D, 0x64, 0x5D, 0x19, 0x73,
                    0x60, 0x81, 0x4F, 0xDC, 0x22, 0x2A, 0x90, 0x88, 0x46, 0xEE, 0xB8, 0x14, 0xDE, 0x5E, 0x0B, 0xDB,
                    0xE0, 0x32, 0x3A, 0x0A, 0x49, 0x06, 0x24, 0x5C, 0xC2, 0xD3, 0xAC, 0x62, 0x91, 0x95, 0xE4, 0x79,
                    0xE7, 0xC8, 0x37, 0x6D, 0x8D, 0xD5, 0x4E, 0xA9, 0x6C, 0x56, 0xF4, 0xEA, 0x65, 0x7A, 0xAE, 0x08,
                    0xBA, 0x78, 0x25, 0x2E, 0x1C, 0xA6, 0xB4, 0xC6, 0xE8, 0xDD, 0x74, 0x1F, 0x4B, 0xBD, 0x8B, 0x8A,
                    0x70, 0x3E, 0xB5, 0x66, 0x48, 0x03, 0xF6, 0x0E, 0x61, 0x35, 0x57, 0xB9, 0x86, 0xC1, 0x1D, 0x9E,
                    0xE1, 0xF8, 0x98, 0x11, 0x69, 0xD9, 0x8E, 0x94, 0x9B, 0x1E, 0x87, 0xE9, 0xCE, 0x55, 0x28, 0xDF,
                    0x8C, 0xA1, 0x89, 0x0D, 0xBF, 0xE6, 0x42, 0x68, 0x41, 0x99, 0x2D, 0x0F, 0xB0, 0x54, 0xBB, 0x16
            };

            constexpr static uint8 INV_S_BOX [256] =
            {
                    0x52, 0x09, 0x6A, 0xD5, 0x30, 0x36, 0xA5, 0x38, 0xBF, 0x40, 0xA3, 0x9E, 0x81, 0xF3, 0xD7, 0xFB,
                    0x7C, 0xE3, 0x39, 0x82, 0x9B, 0x2F, 0xFF, 0x87, 0x34, 0x8E, 0x43, 0x44, 0xC4, 0xDE, 0xE9, 0xCB,
                    0x54, 0x7B, 0x94, 0x32, 0xA6, 0xC2, 0x23, 0x3D, 0xEE, 0x4C, 0x95, 0x0B, 0x42, 0xFA, 0xC3, 0x4E,
                    0x08, 0x2E, 0xA1, 0x66, 0x28, 0xD9, 0x24, 0xB2, 0x76, 0x5B, 0xA2, 0x49, 0x6D, 0x8B, 0xD1, 0x25,
                    0x72, 0xF8, 0xF6, 0x64, 0x86, 0x68, 0x98, 0x16, 0xD4, 0xA4, 0x5C, 0xCC, 0x5D, 0x65, 0xB6, 0x92,
                    0x6C, 0x70, 0x48, 0x50, 0xFD, 0xED, 0xB9, 0xDA, 0x5E, 0x15, 0x46, 0x57, 0xA7, 0x8D, 0x9D, 0x84,
                    0x90, 0xD8, 0xAB, 0x00, 0x8C, 0xBC, 0xD3, 0x0A, 0xF7, 0xE4, 0x58, 0x05, 0xB8, 0xB3, 0x45, 0x06,
                    0xD0, 0x2C, 0x1E, 0x8F, 0xCA, 0x3F, 0x0F, 0x02, 0xC1, 0xAF, 0xBD, 0x03, 0x01, 0x13, 0x8A, 0x6B,
                    0x3A, 0x91, 0x11, 0x41, 0x4F, 0x67, 0xDC, 0xEA, 0x97, 0xF2, 0xCF, 0xCE, 0xF0, 0xB4, 0xE6, 0x73,
                    0x96, 0xAC, 0x74, 0x22, 0xE7, 0xAD, 0x35, 0x85, 0xE2, 0xF9, 0x37, 0xE8, 0x1C, 0x75, 0xDF, 0x6E,
                    0x47, 0xF1, 0x1A, 0x71, 0x1D, 0x29, 0xC5, 0x89, 0x6F, 0xB7, 0x62, 0x0E, 0xAA, 0x18, 0xBE, 0x1B,
                    0xFC, 0x56, 0x3E, 0x4B, 0xC6, 0xD2, 0x79, 0x20, 0x9A, 0xDB, 0xC0, 0xFE, 0x78, 0xCD, 0x5A, 0xF4,
                    0x1F, 0xDD, 0xA8, 0x33, 0x88, 0x07, 0xC7, 0x31, 0xB1, 0x12, 0x10, 0x59, 0x27, 0x80, 0xEC, 0x5F,
                    0x60, 0x51, 0x7F, 0xA9, 0x19, 0xB5, 0x4A, 0x0D, 0x2D, 0xE5, 0x7A, 0x9F, 0x93, 0xC9, 0x9C, 0xEF,
                    0xA0, 0xE0, 0x3B, 0x4D, 0xAE, 0x2A, 0xF5, 0xB0, 0xC8, 0xEB, 0xBB, 0x3C, 0x83, 0x53, 0x99, 0x61,
                    0x17, 0x2B, 0x04, 0x7E, 0xBA, 0x77, 0xD6, 0x26, 0xE1, 0x69, 0x14, 0x63, 0x55, 0x21, 0x0C, 0x7D
            };

            constexpr static uint8 RCON [11] = {0x8d, 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80, 0x1b, 0x36};

            void KeyExpansion(const uint8 key [], uint8 expandedKey[]) const;

            static void KeyScheduleCore (uint8 roundNumber, const uint8 keyIn[4], uint8 keyOut[4]);

            static void AddRoundKey (uint8 state[4][4], const uint8 roundKey[4][4]);

            static void SubBytes (uint8 state[4][4]);

            static void ShiftRows (uint8 state[4][4]);

            static void MixColumns (uint8 state[4][4]);

            static void InvSubBytes (uint8 state[4][4]);

            static void InvShiftRows (uint8 state[4][4]);

            static void InvMixColumns (uint8 state[4][4]);

        public:
            AES () = delete;

            explicit AES (uint16 keyLen);

            explicit AES (const BlockCipher& blockCipher);

            explicit AES (const AES& aes);

            void encrypt(const uint8 input[], const uint8 key[], uint8 output[]) const override;

            void decrypt(const uint8 input[], const uint8 key[], uint8 output[]) const override;
    };
}

#endif // AES_HPP
```

And here's the implementation:

```cpp
/**
 *  @author thomas
 *  @date   01/11/17.
 */

#include <BlockCipher/AES.hpp>

namespace Crypto
{
    AES::AES(uint16 keyLen) : BlockCipher ("AES-" + std::to_string(keyLen), keyLen, 128/8) {}

    AES::AES(const BlockCipher& blockCipher) : BlockCipher (blockCipher) {}

    AES::AES(const AES& aes) : BlockCipher (aes) {}

    void AES::encrypt(const uint8 input[], const uint8 key[], uint8 output[]) const
    {
        /*
         * Initial Set-up phase.
         * Setting some variables like maximum iterators, sizes, IV's, ...
         */

        int8 numRounds = 0;
        uint8 state [4][4]=
        {   {input[0], input[4], input[8], input[12]},
            {input[1], input[5], input[9], input[13]},
            {input[2], input[6], input[10], input[14]},
            {input[3], input[7], input[11], input[15]}  };

        uint8 expandedKeyLength = 0;

        switch (this->keyLen)
        {
            case 128:
            {
                numRounds = 10;
                expandedKeyLength = 176;    // We need 176 bytes, we store blocks of 4 bytes, so 176 / 4
                break;
            }

            case 192:
            {
                numRounds = 12;
                expandedKeyLength = 208;    // We need 208 bytes, we store blocks of 4 bytes, so 208 / 4
                break;
            }

            case 256:
            {
                numRounds = 14;
                expandedKeyLength = 240;    // We need 240 bytes, we store blocks of 4 bytes, so 240 / 4
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Invalid key length, must be 128 bits, 192 bits or 256 bits for AES.");
            }
        }

        uint8 expandedKey [expandedKeyLength];
        this->KeyExpansion(key, expandedKey);

        /*
         * Encryption
         */

        uint8 roundKey [4][4]=
        {   {expandedKey[0], expandedKey[4], expandedKey[8], expandedKey[12]},
            {expandedKey[1], expandedKey[5], expandedKey[9], expandedKey[13]},
            {expandedKey[2], expandedKey[6], expandedKey[10], expandedKey[14]},
            {expandedKey[3], expandedKey[7], expandedKey[11], expandedKey[15]}  };

        AES::AddRoundKey (state, roundKey);

        for (int8 roundCounter = 1; roundCounter <= numRounds; roundCounter++)
        {
            // Can't memcpy this because it involves a transposition
            for (uint8 i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                for (uint8 j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {
                    roundKey[i][j] = expandedKey[(roundCounter * this->blockSize) + (j * 4) + i];
                }
            }

            AES::SubBytes(state);

            AES::ShiftRows(state);

            if (roundCounter != numRounds)
            {
                // Apply MixColumns in all rounds but the last
                AES::MixColumns(state);
            }

            AES::AddRoundKey(state, roundKey);
        }

        // Copying final state to output
        for (uint8 i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            for (uint8 j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                output[(j * 4) + i] = state[i][j];
            }
        }
    };

    void AES::decrypt(const uint8 input[], const uint8 key[], uint8 output[]) const
    {
        /*
         * Initial Set-up phase.
         * Setting some variables like maximum iterators, sizes, IV's, ...
         */

        int8 numRounds = 0;
        uint8 state [4][4]=
        {   {input[0], input[4], input[8], input[12]},
            {input[1], input[5], input[9], input[13]},
            {input[2], input[6], input[10], input[14]},
            {input[3], input[7], input[11], input[15]}  };
        uint8 expandedKeyLength = 0;

        switch (this->keyLen)
        {
            case 128:
            {
                numRounds = 10;
                expandedKeyLength = 176;    // We need 176 bytes, we store blocks of 4 bytes, so 176 / 4
                break;
            }

            case 192:
            {
                numRounds = 12;
                expandedKeyLength = 208;    // We need 208 bytes, we store blocks of 4 bytes, so 208 / 4
                break;
            }

            case 256:
            {
                numRounds = 14;
                expandedKeyLength = 240;    // We need 240 bytes, we store blocks of 4 bytes, so 240 / 4
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Invalid key length, must be 128 bits, 192 bits or 256 bits for AES.");
            }
        }

        uint8 expandedKey [expandedKeyLength];
        this->KeyExpansion(key, expandedKey);

        uint8 roundKey [4][4]=
        {   {expandedKey[expandedKeyLength - 16], expandedKey[expandedKeyLength - 12], expandedKey[expandedKeyLength - 8], expandedKey[expandedKeyLength - 4]},
            {expandedKey[expandedKeyLength - 15], expandedKey[expandedKeyLength - 11], expandedKey[expandedKeyLength - 7], expandedKey[expandedKeyLength - 3]},
            {expandedKey[expandedKeyLength - 14], expandedKey[expandedKeyLength - 10], expandedKey[expandedKeyLength - 6], expandedKey[expandedKeyLength - 2]},
            {expandedKey[expandedKeyLength - 13], expandedKey[expandedKeyLength - 9], expandedKey[expandedKeyLength - 5], expandedKey[expandedKeyLength - 1]}   };

        AES::AddRoundKey(state, roundKey);

        /*
         *  Decryption
         */

        for (int8 roundCounter = (int8)(numRounds - 1); roundCounter >= 0; roundCounter--)
        {
            // Can't memcpy this because it involves a transposition
            for (uint8 i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                for (uint8 j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {
                    roundKey[i][j] = expandedKey[(roundCounter * this->blockSize) + (4 * j)  + i];
                }
            }

            AES::InvShiftRows(state);

            AES::InvSubBytes(state);

            AES::AddRoundKey(state, roundKey);

            if (roundCounter != 0)
            {
                // Apply MixColumns in all rounds but the first
                AES::InvMixColumns(state);
            }
        }

        // Copying final state to output
        for (uint8 i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            for (uint8 j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                output[(j * 4) + i] = state[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    void AES::KeyExpansion(const uint8 key [], uint8 expandedKey[]) const
    {
        uint8 initialKeyLength = 0;
        uint8 expandedKeyLength = 0;
        uint8 n = 0;
        uint8 m = 0;

        switch (this->keyLen)
        {
            case 128:
            {
                n = 16;
                m = 0;
                initialKeyLength = 16;
                expandedKeyLength = 176;    // We need 176 bytes, we store blocks of 4 bytes, so 176 / 4
                break;
            }

            case 192:
            {
                n = 24;
                m = 2;
                initialKeyLength = 24;
                expandedKeyLength = 208;    // We need 208 bytes, we store blocks of 4 bytes, so 208 / 4
                break;
            }

            case 256:
            {
                n = 32;
                m = 3;
                initialKeyLength = 32;
                expandedKeyLength = 240;    // We need 240 bytes, we store blocks of 4 bytes, so 240 / 4
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Invalid key length, must be 128 bits, 192 bits or 256 bits for AES.");
            }
        }

        uint8 keySizeIterator = 0;

        memset(expandedKey, 0, expandedKeyLength);
        memcpy(expandedKey, key, initialKeyLength);

        keySizeIterator += initialKeyLength;

        // Start generating new words
        for (uint8 rconIterator = 1; keySizeIterator < expandedKeyLength; rconIterator++)
        {
            uint8 t [4];
            memcpy(t, expandedKey + (keySizeIterator - 4), 4);  // Get previous 4 bytes

            uint8 g [4];
            KeyScheduleCore(rconIterator, t, g);

            memcpy(t, expandedKey + (keySizeIterator - n), 4 * sizeof(uint8));

            // todo: cast-interpret as 4-byte pointer to reduce to a single XOR operation
            for (uint8 i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                t[i] ^= g[i];
            }

            memcpy(expandedKey + keySizeIterator, t, 4 * sizeof(uint8));
            keySizeIterator += 4;

            for (uint8 i = 0; (i < 3) && (keySizeIterator < expandedKeyLength); i++)
            {
                memcpy(t, expandedKey + (keySizeIterator - 4), 4 * sizeof(uint8));

                uint32* resultPtr = (uint32*)(expandedKey + keySizeIterator);
                uint32* tPtr = (uint32*)t;
                uint32* rhsPtr = (uint32*)(expandedKey + keySizeIterator - n);

                *resultPtr = *tPtr ^ *rhsPtr;
                /*
                for (uint8 j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {
                    expandedKey[keySizeIterator + j] = t[j] ^ expandedKey[keySizeIterator - n + j];
                }
                */

                keySizeIterator += 4;
            }

            if ((this->keyLen == 256)  && (keySizeIterator < expandedKeyLength))
            {
                memcpy(t, expandedKey + (keySizeIterator - 4), 4 * sizeof(uint8));  // Get previous 4 bytes

                for (uint8 i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
                    t[i] = S_BOX[t[i]];
                }

                uint32* resultPtr = (uint32*)(expandedKey + keySizeIterator);
                uint32* tPtr = (uint32*)t;
                uint32* rhsPtr = (uint32*)(expandedKey + keySizeIterator - n);

                *resultPtr = *tPtr ^ *rhsPtr;

                /*
                for (uint8 i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
                    expandedKey[keySizeIterator + i] = t[i] ^ expandedKey[keySizeIterator - n + i];
                    //t[i] ^= expandedKey[keySizeIterator - n - 4 + i];
                }
                */

                //memcpy(expandedKey + (keySizeIterator - 3 - 1), t, 4 * sizeof(uint8));
                keySizeIterator += 4;
            }

            for (uint8 i = 0; (i < m) && (keySizeIterator < expandedKeyLength); i++)
            {
                memcpy(t, expandedKey + (keySizeIterator - 4), 4 * sizeof(uint8));  // Get previous 4 bytes

                uint32* resultPtr = (uint32*)(expandedKey + keySizeIterator);
                uint32* tPtr = (uint32*)t;
                uint32* rhsPtr = (uint32*)(expandedKey + keySizeIterator - n);

                *resultPtr = *tPtr ^ *rhsPtr;

                /*
                for (uint8 j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {
                    expandedKey[keySizeIterator + j] = t[j] ^ expandedKey[keySizeIterator - n + j];
                }
                */
                keySizeIterator += 4;
            }
        }
    }

    void AES::KeyScheduleCore(uint8 roundNumber, const uint8 keyIn[4], uint8 keyOut[4])
    {
        //todo memcpy
        //for (uint8 i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        //{
        //  keyOut[i] = keyIn[i];
        //}
        memcpy(keyOut, keyIn, 4);
        //keyOut = keyIn;

        // Rotate
        uint8 tmp = keyOut[0];

        for (uint8 i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            keyOut[i] = keyOut[i+1];
        }

        keyOut[3] = tmp;

        // Substitute
        for (uint8 i = 0; i < sizeof(uint32); i++)
        {
            keyOut[i] = AES::S_BOX[keyOut[i]];
        }

        // Apply RCON to rightmost byte
        keyOut[0] = keyOut[0] ^ RCON[roundNumber];
    }

    void AES::AddRoundKey(uint8 state[4][4], const uint8 roundKey[4][4])
    {
        for (uint8 i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            uint32* keyPtr = (uint32*) roundKey[i];
            uint32* statePtr = (uint32*) state[i];
            *statePtr ^= *keyPtr;
            /*
            for (uint8 j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                state[i][j] ^= roundKey[i][j];
            }
             */
        }
    }

    void AES::SubBytes(uint8 state[4][4])
    {
        for (uint8 i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            for (uint8 j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                state[i][j] = AES::S_BOX[state[i][j]];
            }
        }
    }

    void AES::ShiftRows(uint8 state[4][4])
    {
        for (uint8 i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            if (i > 0)
            {
                uint8 row [4];
                for (uint8 j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {
                    row[j] = state[i][j];
                }

                for (uint8 j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {
                    state[i][j] = row[(i + j) % 4]; // I got this formula by first writing down all shifts
                                                    // And then collapsing/generalizing them piece-by-piece
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void AES::MixColumns(uint8 state[4][4])
    {
        for (uint8 i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            uint8 col [4] = {state[0][i], state[1][i], state[2][i], state[3][i]};

            state[0][i] = GALOIS_TABLE_2[col[0]] ^ GALOIS_TABLE_3[col[1]] ^ col[2] ^ col[3];
            state[1][i] = col[0] ^ GALOIS_TABLE_2[col[1]] ^ GALOIS_TABLE_3[col[2]] ^ col[3];
            state[2][i] = col[0] ^ col[1] ^ GALOIS_TABLE_2[col[2]] ^ GALOIS_TABLE_3[col[3]];
            state[3][i] = GALOIS_TABLE_3[col[0]] ^ col[1] ^ col[2] ^ GALOIS_TABLE_2[col[3]];
        }
    }

    void AES::InvSubBytes(uint8 state[4][4])
    {
        for (uint8 i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            for (uint8 j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                state[i][j] = INV_S_BOX[state[i][j]];
            }
        }
    }

    void AES::InvShiftRows(uint8 state[4][4])
    {
        for (uint8 i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            if (i > 0)
            {
                uint8 row [4];
                for (uint8 j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {
                    row[j] = state[i][j];
                }

                for (int8 j = 3; j >= 0; j--)
                {
                    state[i][j] = row[(j + (4- i)) % 4];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void AES::InvMixColumns(uint8 state[4][4])
    {
        for (uint8 i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            uint8 col [4] = {state[0][i], state[1][i], state[2][i], state[3][i]};

            state[0][i] = GALOIS_TABLE_14[col[0]] ^ GALOIS_TABLE_11[col[1]] ^ GALOIS_TABLE_13[col[2]] ^ GALOIS_TABLE_9[col[3]];
            state[1][i] = GALOIS_TABLE_9[col[0]] ^ GALOIS_TABLE_14[col[1]] ^ GALOIS_TABLE_11[col[2]] ^ GALOIS_TABLE_13[col[3]];
            state[2][i] = GALOIS_TABLE_13[col[0]] ^ GALOIS_TABLE_9[col[1]] ^ GALOIS_TABLE_14[col[2]] ^ GALOIS_TABLE_11[col[3]];
            state[3][i] = GALOIS_TABLE_11[col[0]] ^ GALOIS_TABLE_13[col[1]] ^ GALOIS_TABLE_9[col[2]] ^ GALOIS_TABLE_14[col[3]];
        }
    }
}
```

I've verified the correctness of my implementation using [NIST test vectors](https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/publications/fips/197/final/documents/fips-197.pdf), used ECB vectors for verifying the actual algorithm and used the CBC vectors to verify that my CBC is working correctly) and catch unit tests.

I should note that I would like to avoid using the AES-NI processor extension. I know it can speed up my implementation quite a bit, but it would defeat the purpose of implementing it in the first place.

**NOTE:** This code is not intended for professional use. It is a personal project, but since people are always saying it's almost impossible to "do crypto right", I figured I'd give it a go.

I was linking my Release-Build-Performance-Tester to a Debug-Built version of my library, which resulted in a debug-version of my Performance tester, After building my library as a release build. This is the performance I get:

```
Read file, filesize 10878713B, 10.3747MB
Done padding
Encryption of 10878713B (10.3747MB) took 929.581ms
Average speed of 11.1607MB/s
Decryption of 10878713B (10.3747MB) took 764.709ms
Average speed of 13.5669MB/s
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68461/discussion-on-question-by-shmoo6000-aes-implementation-in-c).

Comment: This is an old thread so I don't know if you are monitoring it anymore. But can you elaborate on what you said?

"I should note that I would like to avoid using the AES-NI processor extension. I know it can speed up my implementation quite a bit, but it would defeat the purpose of implementing it in the first place."

Comment: There's x86 assembly instructions that perform AES, Thesd are called the AES-NI instructions, they are much faster than a/my software implementation (upwards of 700MB/s), But if I used them, well..., I wouldn't be implementing AES, I'd just be using Intel's implementation. Here's some info on AES-NI: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but unless you are implementing AES just as an exercise, why wouldn't you take advantage of the hardware acceleration if supported? Is it more vulnerable to certain attacks?

Comment: You're completely right, if your platform supports these extensions and you're writing production code, you should use the AES-NI extensions. I was implementing AES for the fun of it though ('as an exercise'), so using the extensions would defeat the whole point of implementing AES in the first place

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> I'm looking to improve the code to make it not "DIY-crypto-bad", if at
>   all possible

I work in security. This is not my area, but I have a non-zero amount of knowledge on implementing secure cryptographic primitives, and from a cursory look I found some issues.

For starters:

```
keyOut[i] = AES::S_BOX[keyOut[i]];
```

and

```
state[i][j] = AES::S_BOX[state[i][j]];
```

and

```
state[i][j] = INV_S_BOX[state[i][j]];
```

You are indexing into an array using secret information, which means that your memory accesses and cache timings will vary depending on this secret information. An attacker can measure your execution time (or power consumption) to steal such information. This is called a ["side channel attack"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side-channel_attack).

Also, note that AES+CBC without an HMAC is not sufficient in most cases. You still need a way to ensure integrity, i.e. the decrypted plaintext has not been tampered. People naively think that any change to the ciphertext will completely garble the decrypted plaintext, but this is not actually true for CBC. For example, if you flip one bit in a block, it'll indeed garble that block, but the next block will be ok except for having a flipped bit in the same position. [Here's an exercise](https://cryptopals.com/sets/2/challenges/16) where the goal is to change the text inside a ciphertext without having the key.

On the same vein of not checking for integrity, there's also the [Padding Oracle Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_oracle_attack) that enables an attacker to completely decrypt a ciphertext only by submitting ciphertexts and observing if the padding was correct or not.

There may or may not be other errors, but this is a good place to start. If you want more examples on how cryptosystems get broken, I recommend the [Cryptopals Challenge](https://cryptopals.com/). It's very hands-on and an eye opener on why DIY-crypto is hard.

EDIT: I see some answers in the chat suggesting that the timing attacks should be protected by using threads that `sleep` for a fixed amount of time. I don't think that's sound, and I've never seen it done in verified implementations. [Here's a question from crypto.stackexchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/55/known-methods-for-constant-time-table-free-aes-implementation-using-standard) on how to properly protect yourself from this.

Comment: While I understand how indexing into an array can lead to me leaking information, I don't really see how this can be avoided. This is how S-Boxes work right, you give them 1 byte and they return another, with no (clear) relation between the two. Since I uploaded my question I believe I also changed my Galois Multiplication to use lookup tables, so again, how can I use these without indexing based on secret (or secret-dependant) data?

Comment: @shmoo6000 You don't. You can't make such table look-ups secure. A proper SW-only implementation would use a bit-sliced implementation (which is also faster).

Comment: In particular, @shmoo6000 where is your interpretive dance that compares various side channel attacks? (See the "foot shooting agreement" in [A Stick Figure Guide to AES](http://www.moserware.com/2009/09/stick-figure-guide-to-advanced.html))

Comment: @shmoo6000 you might be interested in reading the followings answers on cryptoSE: 
[AES S-Box implementation: from a byte-by-byte to 2-bytes-by-2bytes?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/52728/29161)  // [Timing attack and good coding practices](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/41698/29161) // 
[Different ways/algorithms for implementing AES](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/44675/29161) // 
[Implementing AES 2000-2010:
performance and security challenges (pdf)](https://www.hyperelliptic.org/SPEED/slides09/kasper-aes_speedcc09_slides.pdf)

Comment: @Biv, Wow, thank you very much, that's actually a really clear example of what Bit Slicing means, aloing with Martin Bonner's mathematical explanation of the math behind the S-Box'es I can add this to my Implementation! Martin Bonner, I'm not much of a dancer, but this is definitely not production code, basically, I'm just trying to learn what it means to create "Proper Crypto".

Comment: @Biv Don't forget our ursine overlord's [page about constant time](https://www.bearssl.org/constanttime.html) crypto!

Comment: @Biv I have a question regarding AES bitslicing, let's say I attempt to implement an AES S-box with bitslicing, do I have to take in multiple 16-byte blocks and slice those together, or can I take 1 16-byte block and slice the separate bytes from that block together?

Answer (score 27):

Since there are only three valid key sizes for AES, it makes sense to not even let the AES class be instantiated with any `uint16` value. I would introduce an enum similar to this:

```
enum class AesKeyLen
{
    Aes128,
    Aes192,
    Aes256
};
```

And then change the `uint16` constructor to this:

```
explicit AES (AesKeyLen keyLen);
```

Sure, they could still pass bad values, but they have to try harder by explicitly creating an invalid enum value. Also, making it a scoped enum provides extra type-safety and prevents naming clashes.

Either way, I think it makes sense to throw out of the constructor immediately if the key length is wrong instead of waiting until the `encrypt` function.

If you want to enforce a valid value at compile-time, you can use a `static_assert`, or you can use a smart-enum pattern. This is an example hacked together real quick:

```
class AesKeyLen
{    
private:
    uint16 _length;

    AesKeyLen(uint16 len)
    {
        _length = len;
    }

public:
    uint16 length()
    {
        return _length;
    }

    static AesKeyLen Aes128()
    {
        return AesKeyLen(128);
    }

    static AesKeyLen Aes192()
    {
        return AesKeyLen(192);
    }

    static AesKeyLen Aes256()
    {
        return AesKeyLen(256);
    }
};
```

And then replace the `uint16` constructor again:

```
explicit AES (AesKeyLen keyLen);
```

Comment: There is little point moving to static constructors over a single enum-constructor: if someone is foolish enough to try and circumvent the enum, they are foolish enough to overwrite the memory in your class instance. Also known as *You can protect against Murphy, but not against Machiavelli*.

Comment: Integers are never implicitly cast even into unscoped enums (unlike enum-to-int casts) — this was since the first C++ standard. You must be confusing with the C behavior, where casts in both directions are implicit.

Answer (score 15):

Interface Design:

```
        void encrypt(const uint8 input[], const uint8 key[], uint8 output[]) const override;

        void decrypt(const uint8 input[], const uint8 key[], uint8 output[]) const override;
```

Your encrypt and decrypt is very limiting. This means you need to load the whole of your input into memory before you can start any operations. It would be nicer to have a stream/iterator like interface that allowed you simply read the data as needed.

```
        void encrypt(std::istream& input, const uint8 key[], std::ostream& output) const override;

        void decrypt(std::istream& input, const uint8 key[], std::ostream& output) const override;
```

Coding wise there is nothing really interesting to comment on. It looks pretty bog standard simple code. I don't see any clear performance killers.

Comment: You're right that I need to load the whole of my input into memory, but AES works on 128 bit (16 byte) blocks. Is that really so bad? It wouldn't work on a stream anyway because it needs those 16 bytes to work. If you want AES to work like a stream (cipher) you need another mode of operation (I believe this is possible in CFB and OFB)

Comment: Why can't you just read 16 bytes from the stream at a time. Encrypt/Decrypt write the resulting value to the output. Repeat until end of stream.

Comment: That would be ECB mode, and you don't want to encourage using it by making it the default.

Comment: @milleniumbug, the proposed interface doesn't prevent the programmer from providing a block mode (such as CBC using a random IV internally) when initializing the class.

Comment: I don't see how providing the data via a stream or a static array changes how an internal encryption mode is set! This is just a way to get the data  into the algorithm.

Comment: AES is a cryptographic primitive. It works on 16-byte blocks, no more, no less. If you want to encrypt more, you need to use a 'Chaining mode' or 'Block Cipher mode of operation'. This is not part of the algorithm itself. The way you suggest feeding data to the algorithm is called ECB and considered insecure.

Comment: Yes its a block encryption algorithm. I understand this. It does not change my original statement. But Now I see you have additional issues in that your encryption only encrypts blocks of 16 bytes. Normally you encrypt streams of bytes. When I encrypt a file its a stream of bytes the outout is a stream. So I have to chunk it into 16 bytes chunks but that is not an issue.

Comment: @Loki, you're right that being able to use a cipher with C++ streams would be very useful.  I disagree with you that including that functionality at this level would be a good thing.  To my mind, that's something that would make a nice next-layer interface, making use of block-cipher primitives and providing the chaining and padding needed to make a stream-cipher.  I'd definitely want to keep its implementation away from the details of implementing the block cipher.

Comment: There's no reason that feeding 16-bytes at a time would limit you to ECB-mode, providing the class retained the necessary state between calls to allow it to do the necessary XOR with the counter or previous block etc...

Comment: @TobySpeight This isn't about using it as a stream cipher, this is about limiting memory footprint by not requiring the entire 68GB file to be loaded in memory all at once.

Comment: An iterator interface would let you use the same AES code with other "array-like" things rather than just arrays. For instance, an iterator that transparently loads and caches sections of a large file. Or an iterator that generates the plaintext blocks on-the-fly as the cipher needs them as part of a pipeline.

Comment: @AJMansfield: I think you misunderstand the usage of `encrypt`. It is not a function that encrypts 68 GB of memory; it is a function that encrypts 16 bytes of memory.

Comment: @LokiAstari: I think you're misunderstanding the usage of `encrypt` as well; see my comment immediately above. I suppose the real lesson for the OP to learn from this answer is "you should document your functions".

Answer (score 13):

I think the header could be trimmed down a lot. The constant tables belong in the implementation file since they are not needed for the definition of the class.

Since the AES class does not hold any state (except for that inherited from `BlockCipher`), I would not declare the private functions in the header, but only keep them in the implementation file in an anonymous namespace.

The code `for (i = 0; i < n; i++) if (i > 0)` can be written shorter, as `for (i = 1; …`.

Comment: I also thought about making the private static methods just regular static functions, but I didn't want to pollute the "Crypto" namespace with functions that shouldn't be accessed by anyone but the AES algorithm. I thought about creating an "AES" namespace, but that created naming conflicts, instead of renaming it to "AES_Utils" or something, I just decided to make the functions private methods. **Edit: I just noticed you said "static" functions, so no namespace pollution in that case, That might actually be a good idea, thanks!"**

Comment: If you look at the KeyExpansion, you can see that it uses the value "rconIterator" for the KeyScheduleCore. rconIterator is raised by one every "round" of key expansion. In a round of key expansion for AES128, you add 16 bytes, for AES192 you add 24 bytes, for AES256 you add 32 bytes. This confirms Wikipedia, in that you need less RCON values for longer keys: "Only the first some of these constants are actually used – up to rcon[10] for AES-128 (as 11 round keys are needed), up to rcon[8] for AES-192, up to rcon[7] for AES-256." (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_key_schedule#Rcon)

Comment: Ah, thanks, it's confusing when the term _round_ is used with two different meanings in the same algorithm. :)

Comment: Instead of static functions, anonymous namespace should be used since we are talking about C++.

Answer (score 11):

You don't show us the `BlockCipher` base class, but it appears that it imposes a terrible interface on us:

```
void encrypt(const uint8 input[], const uint8 key[], uint8 output[])
    const override;

void decrypt(const uint8 input[], const uint8 key[], uint8 output[])
    const override;
```

I'm assuming that `uint8` is a simple typedef of `std::uint8_t` (though not sure why you don't go the whole hog and call it `u8` as many abbreviators do).

The problem here is that we don't get any compile-time checking of the correctness of the arguments.  As our input and output block sizes are fixed at 128 bits, I'd expect something more like:

```
void encrypt(const uint8 (&input)[16], const uint8 key[], uint8 (&output)[16])
    const override;
// and a similar decrypt
```

Or possibly even

```
void encrypt(const InputBlock& input, const Key& key, OutputBlock& output)
    const override;
```

where the array types can be defined by `BlockCipher` if it's declared as

```
class BlockCipher<std::size_t KeySize,
                  std::size_t InputSize,
                  std::size_t OutputSize = InputSize>
```

Answer (score 4):

As other have said, an AES implementation should also be secured against [timing/cache attacks](https://cr.yp.to/antiforgery/cachetiming-20050414.pdf) and other fun side-channels.

And as explained in the linked crypto.SE QA, you should typically avoid all non-constant operations on secret data, and yet currently you're relying on table lookups as explained in BoppreH's answer, as anybody implementing AES from scratch would.
But those are not [constant-time](https://www.bearssl.org/constanttime.html).

I recommend you read [that link](https://www.bearssl.org/constanttime.html), which talks about a constant time implementation of AES. As explained there, the usual way to obtain a constant-time AES implementation is to perform "bit-slicing". Bit-slicing implies working at the bit level, with bitwise operations that are directly constant-time and to basically build an "AES" boolean circuit and translate it into C(++) code.
Yet, this is not the only way, since the table is just a [memoized function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) in the end, you could also compute the function explicitly at each iteration, if you do not care much about performances.

Finally you might be asking yourself why it is always a bad idea to roll your own crypto and to publish it on the net, that is mostly because you'll end up with other people able to take your implementation to do their stuff without caring about the security implications...
For example, the Matrix's OLM library is relying on a non constant time [AES implementation](https://git.matrix.org/git/olm/tree/lib/crypto-algorithms/aes.c), even if its creator, Brad Conte, actually [said about it](https://github.com/B-Con/crypto-algorithms/blob/master/README.md) that:

> "Note that these are not cryptographically secure implementations."